# How to set and destroy a session variable in struts2?

Tags: struts2, session-variables, destroy

I'm a beginner in Struts2. I am used in PHP, while logging to save authentification in a **session** variable, which I can destroy after logging out. I wonder how I can do the same process in Struts2 : to **set** a **session** variable while logging in and to **destroy** it while logging out. Thank you a lot.

**Update ( An additional solution )**

In addition to the useful answers and comments, we can use :

```
session.remove("session_var_name"); // instead of session.clear();
```

to remove one exact session variable instead of removing all the session variables. Thank you all.

Comment: if you can google it by yourself, it takes little time. Session: `Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();`, for `log out` you can do `session.clear();`

Comment: I found a solution about implementing SessionAware class, they didn't mention Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession(), is it thanks of implementing that interface? or only they forgot the instruction u said? thanks

Comment: Hi, you do not need to implement `SessionAware`, check the api doc of `ActionContext.SESSION`, you can get the session already when you in a servlet environment. http://struts.apache.org/2.0.6/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionContext.html

Comment: @Jaiwo99 But you *should* implement `SessionAware`, it is preferred for testability reasons over `ActionContext`. Also, please try not to link to ancient versions of the docs, especially when the current version doesn't live in the same place :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do one of the following

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware
{
    private HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;

    public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        this.httpServletRequest = request;
    }

    public String login()
    {
        httpServletRequest.getSession(false).setAttribute("key", your_session_object);
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String logout()
    {
        httpServletRequest.getSession(false).removeAttribute("key");
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}

public class MyAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware
{
    private Map sessionMap;

    public void setSession(Map map)
    {
        this.sessionMap = map;
    }

    public String login()
    {
        sessionMap.put(key, your_session_object);
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String logout()
    {
        sessionMap.remove(key);
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

The second alternative i.e. implementing `SessionAware` is preferred since it shields you from `Servlet` APIs.

Comment: With the caveat that using `ServletRequestAware` would almost never be preferred since it ties your action to the servlet API.

Comment: @DaveNewton You are right, but he needs to be aware of `ServletRequestAware` since it also get the job done. I will edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Scope Interceptor when you call logout, and with "end" type in your struts xml configuration, Interceptor set null to your session object:

```
<action name="scopea" class="com.mevipro.test.action.ScopeActionA">
    <result name="success" type="dispatcher">/jsp/test.jsp</result>
    <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="scope">
        <param name="key">funky</param>
        <param name="session">person</param>
        <param name="type">start</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
</action>
<action name="scopeb" class="com.mevipro.test.action.ScopeActionB">
    <result name="success" type="dispatcher">/jsp/test.jsp</result>
    <interceptor-ref name="scope">
        <param name="key">funky</param>
        <param name="session">person</param>
        <param name="type">end</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>
</action>
```

you must define "start" and "end" the start is when you initialise your object in session and the "end" for destroy your object

For more detail : https://struts.apache.org/docs/scope-interceptor.html